# Convergence to a constant or not? Reference request

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, limits-and-convergence

Consider the function

$$f(n) = \log n /(n\ \log\theta(p_n)),$$

where $\theta$ is the first Chebyshev function and $p_n$ is the $n$-th prime. Does $f$ converge to a constant as $n$ grows to infinity, or does it grow to infinity; and if it converges to a constant, what would that constant be? In either case, if you can answer the question, can you prove it or provide a reference to read about it?

Comment: the function $\theta(n)$ grows like $n\log n$ so $f(n)$ goes to zero more rapidly than $1/n$ for large $n$.

Comment: The reason I am not sure is that if you take $\sigma(N)/(N\ \log\ \theta(n))$ that decreases, but it goes to $e^\gamma/\zeta(2)$, not to 0. And on my computer, it seems to grow at first, at least up to n= 10^8.

Comment: $\sigma(n) < \log n$

Comment: That was meant to be $\sigma(N) < \log n$, where $N$ is the n-t primorial, but I cannot edit the comment above nor delete it.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker $\theta(n)$ is asymptotically $n$. That is, $\theta(n)/n$ tends to $1$.

Comment: Your function is at most $(\log n)/(n\log 2)$, hence it tends to zero quite rapidly.

Comment: @GH from MO - right, I want to close the question, but it doesn't let me. I realize I made a mistake in posing the question. Apologies. Can one of you just close it?

Answer (score 1):

The prime number theorem suggests that $\theta(x)\sim x$, so we have

$$
f(n)\sim{\log n\over n\log n}=\frac1n\to0
$$

Comment: The statement $\theta(x)\sim x$ is not suggested by the prime number theorem: it is a form of the prime number theorem. Note also that $\log\theta(n)\sim\log n$ is a much weaker statement, e.g. it follows from Chebyshev's estimate $\theta(x)\asymp x$. Finally, as I said in my remark, the trivial bound $\theta(n)\geq\log 2$ already implies that $f(n)$ tends to zero.